# Publishing a Google Slides add-on

Tags: google-slides-api, google-apps-script-addon

I would like to ask you for some advice: I developed a really simple Google Slides add-on that makes my life easier when I use slides. The problem is that the instructions seem to be so generic for diverse google products (apps, extensions, addons, etc) and I think I'm missing something.

I followed the instructions in the official docs. I created a script with the Scripts Editor and I choose to publish it as an addon. I completed the required fields and I was redirected to the Deveoper Dashboard, that does not let me upload the add-on with no manifest file. At this point, a manifest wasn't required by Google Slides, so I created one with no much idea and validating it with the error messages that the uploading tool throws. It is something like this:
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "The name",
  "version": "2",
  "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}

I was able to upload that manifest, but the package is listed as a Chrome extension and not as a Google Slides add-on (creating a new slide and accessing document > addons > download addons).

I spent 5 hours reading how to do it ok, but I could not achieve it and I'm really tired of guessing. Can anyone point me to a concrete documentation/tutorial/video in a concrete Google Slides scenario?

PS: if I try to update the add-on from the Script Editor, by publishing it again, it tells me "This item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest". But there is no manifest in the Script Editor, and there is no app field in the manifest uploaded in the Deveoper Dashboard. And by the way, publishing in the Deveoper Dashboard forces you to have a manifest...

Thanks, thanks, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create and publish Google Slides add-on, follow these steps:

1. Open https://drive.google.com.
2. Create new Google Apps Script project by selecting **New - More - Google Apps Script**.

[image]

3. Save project by selecting from Google Apps Script editor menu **File - Save**.
4. Popup window will ask you to enter your project's name, fill it and press **OK**.

[image]

5. *Code your add-on functionality*.
6. For publishing add-on, select from Google Apps Script editor menu **Publish - Deploy as web add-on..**.

[image]

7. In opened modal, fill needed details (Add-on Type: *Slides*; Version: *New*; Post-install tip) and click **Create web store draft**.

[image]

8. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/ADDON_ID will open.

[image]

9. Scroll down the page and click **Publish changes**.

[image]

10. Your add-on is published!

Comment: Thank you so much Kos! This is much better thanthe oficia docs. But I can not publish because of the manifest, again. This time the message is "API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace SDK enabled". In which point should I add a manifest? And which are the expected properties? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I finally managed to upload the file from the Chrome Web store but I was required to enable the Google Marketplace SDK, which I have to enable by creating a new item. When I dothat, the script ID is required to be associated to the project, but for some reason I go to (File > Propect Properties) and the ID says "deprecated". Anyway, when I try to associate it in the G Suite Marketplace SDK config tab, It tells me the ID do not exist... I think the official docs should provide a full step by step tutorial, otherwise developing is REALLY frustrating. I just wanted to help other users :(

Comment: In step 8 you have to upload a package that you don't have. Let's suppose you manually create a folder with the files of your addon (because neither Google Scripts nor Google Drive allows you to download your current project files). Then, the uploading tool asks for things that are not compatible with what the scripts editor allows you to include. E.g. the script editor do not allow you to change the appsscript.json to manifest.json, or the api_console_project_id field is not allowed in the script editor to be saved, but the uploading tool requires it.

Comment: @gal007 actually interface for step 8 is old and confusing. In the reality when you click "Create draft" on step 7, Google uploads that package for you, you don't need to upload it yourself, just click "Publish changes" and you good to go.